# Eloquent hasManyThrough also get middle table information

Tags: laravel, relationship, has-many-through

I have same table structure as mentioned in laravel document for HasManyThrough relationship [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

```
countries
  id - integer
  name - string 

users
  id - integer
  country_id - integer
  name - string

posts
  id - integer
  user_id - integer
  title - string
```

and define a relationship like same as in doc.

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Post', 'App\User',
        'country_id', 'user_id', 'id'
    );
}
```

Now when I List posts of specific country. I need the information of user of the post too. I mean information from pivot table(users)

```
$posts = Country::find(2)->posts();
```

The above returns post data only..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to eager load the users alongside the posts, can be achieved via the `with()` method on the Builder:

```
$posts = Country::find(2)->posts()->with('user')->get();
```

If you're loading huge amounts of data and don't want the whole `User` instance loaded, you can even specify which fields to only be retrieved from the users table:

```
$posts = Country::find(2)->posts()->with('user:id,name')->get();
```

Then you can simply use `$post->user->name` or whatever you need when iterating your collection.

Refer to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for more information.

Comment: for eager loading first I need to define relationship between post and user right...? Or It will work with my currention defined hasManyThrough relationship?

Comment: You'll have to define the relationship in the `Post` model, but I'd say it's worth the effort. You may need the relationship later on as well, it's not going to be obsolete since it exists anyway. :)

Comment: Thanks... Its working.. I was just stick with hasManyThrough relationship to find a way out. and haven't think about other relationship to take in picture..

Comment: one more help needed. this gives me error. 
Country::find(2)->posts()->with('user:id,name')->get();

insted of id my column name is id_user

Comment: Well that was only an example, of course you must change `id` with `user_id` if that matches your column's name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$posts = Country::find(2)->posts()->with('user')->get();
```